# How to get SOAP last request with SoapClient even if the request was not succesful?

Tags: php, soap, request, soap-client

Apparently the $SoapClient->__getLastRequest() works only if the request is successful. Which is kind of useless because I need to see the request as a plain XML to find the errors..

Is there any way to get the last request from the SoapClient anyway?

Comment: It will work either way, but you have to have trace option set to true i.e. `$soapclient = new SoapClient($uri, array('trace' => 1,'exceptions' => true));`